# Notificações Push no Android com PWA

Tags: android, pwa

Tenho uma PWA(Progressive Web Application) que foi criado utilizando o VueJS em conjunto com um sistema web.

E para as notificações push foi utilizado o Firebase Cloud Messaging, porém estou com um problema na hora de receber as notificações push com o PWA instalado no smartphone, as notificações não aparecem.

Utilizando o sistema no computador as notificações são entregues dentro do normal, porém no smartphone, tanto no chrome quanto com o PWA instalado as notificações não chegam.

As notificações push funcionam somente para app's nativos Android??

Comment: Funcionam sim, mas precisa da autorização do usuário também, da uma olhada aqui: https://ada.is/progressive-web-apps-talk/

Comment: Vou fazer alguns testes aqui e se eu não der a resposta se funcionou ainda hoje eu respondo amanhã... Agradeço a ajuda @DavidDias

Comment: Estou seguindo o exemplo que é feito no artigo, porém estou tendo problemas na hora de registrar o `service-worker`...

Comment: @LeonardoEbert conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As notificações via push funcionam sim via PWA, com exceção para o iOS (até o momento sem suporte).
Este link mostra um tutorial de como testar (em inglês):
https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications

Aqui você pode acompanhar os navegadores e sistemas que suportam a notificação via push:
https://whatwebcando.today/push-notifications.html